# C# - Truncate beginning of large transaction log file

Tags: c#, file-io, transactions

I'm using a text file as a way to store transactions.  This transaction log is essentially the persistence mechanism.  When the software bootstraps it will replay the transactions and get back to the last known state.  There are other things like snapshots, loading transactions after the snapshot was taken (to stop from replaying from the beginning of time), archiving, and purging.

These transaction logs can get really large.  This is especially true when a company wants to keep a month's worth of transactions.  The archive is purged of old transactions at startup and then every midnight (snapshots taken, transactions archived, and then old ones purged).

The algorithm used to purge is to open two file streams; one for the current file and another for a temp file that gets created.  I stream one transaction at a time to the temporary file only writing the ones I want.  Then I delete the current file and rename the temp file to be the current file.  This approach saves on RAM but performance becomes a problem for files approaching 500mb.

The transactions are stored oldest on the top to newest on the bottom.  What I would like to do is remove one line at a time until I find a transaction that needs to stay and then stop processing.  Is there a way to do that?  Below is the current approach:

```cs
await _semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
try
{
    using var reader = _fileSystem.OpenStream(originalFile);
    using var writer = _fileSystem.CreateStream(tempFile);
    string? line = null;
    while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)) is not null)
    {
        var logItem = _serializer.Deserialize<TransactionLogItem>(line);
        var dateLogged = logItem.HappenedOn.ToLocalDateTime().Date;
        if (dateLogged >= oldestAllowedDate) await writer.WriteLineAsync(line).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
finally
{
    _fileSystem.DeleteFile(originalFile);
    _fileSystem.Rename(tempFile, originalFile);
    _semaphore.Release();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do that?

No; no file system supports truncating the *beginning* of a file. You can kinda get something working maybe with sparse files, but they only work on some filesystems and are pretty coarse in what sections can be made sparse.

Your best bet is to either do what you're doing now, use a real database, or have multiple transaction logs so you can just delete old ones.